# How to interpret coverage summary from mono profiler report

Tags: xamarin, mono, profiling, code-coverage, nunit-console

I created a unit test project for a PCL in a Xamarin Application. I am running on console:

```
    mono --debug  --profile=log:coverage,report,covfilter=+MyProject.Core.Contacts.ViewModels.ContactsViewModel \
    ../nunit3-console.exe \
    --noh \
    --inprocess \
    --noresult \
    ../MyProject.Core.Tests.dll
```

I take this as coverage summary:

```
Coverage Summary:
    Brabbler.Core (/Users/Stam/Projects/MyProject/tests/Core/MyProject.Core.Tests/bin/Debug/MyProject.Core.dll) 0% covered (2260 methods - 9 covered)
        MyProject.Core.Contacts.ViewModels.ContactCellViewModel 25% covered (32 methods - 8 covered)
        MyProject.Core.Contacts.ViewModels.ContactCellViewModel.<DeleteContact>c__async0 50% covered (2 methods - 1 covered)
```

1. How can I interpret this report?
2. The ContactCellViewModel has only 3 methods, why it reports 32 methods?
3. What does mean that the ContactCellViewMode is 25% covered?

Comment: I would **assume** that your `ContactCellViewModel` class has 1 `ctor`, 3 methods and 14 properties... so 32 = 1 + 3 + (14 * 2) (default prop getters and setters are code generated methods in IL)

Comment: @SushiHangover is there any way to take more information? Like how many lines of code are tested?

Comment: The built-in `coverage` profiler in Mono is really limited in **and by** design and is not a line-by-line code analysis tool as it is using built-in runtime events. You can use  There are some OSS such as `XR.Mono.Cover` that execute your code via the Mono soft debugger thus "see" every line of code  executed (and not) and thus can produce detailed reports. Personally on macOS I use a custom version of `XR.Mono.Cover` along with `ReportGenerator` ( https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator ) to produce detailed line-by-line coverage reports...

Comment: On Windows, I use dotCover, part of Resharper Ultimate licensing... On Windows there are LOTS of options but on Linux and macOS your options are pretty limited....

Comment: FYI: You can use `ReportGenerator` ( github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator ) with Mono coverage and use `mprof-report` to process the `output.mlpd` files to coverage `.xml` output and use `ReportGenerator` to produce *pretty* html-based reports, but it will show that the entire method (all code lines) is tested, which might not be true...

Comment: @SushiHangover Well I would like to have line-by-line coverage if is that possible. What do you mean custom version of `XR.Mono.Cover` and do you know if it is compatible with mono 4?

Comment: `XR.Mono.Cover` (or XR.Baboon never sure what name to use) works with Mono 4.x. By custom version I mean I am using a modified version of it (IDE integration, automatic `ReportGenerator` integration, xUnit/nUnit for Device support, ... )

Comment: https://github.com/inorton/XR.Baboon can now produce ReportGenerator-like output, showing line-by-line coverage. (Disclosure: I implemented this enhancement, and seeing this I wish I'd known about ReportGenerator at that time.)